# Как пользователю внутри контейнера Docker дать права доступа к docker на хостовой системе

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, jenkins

jenkins:
image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
user: '1000'
volumes:
- ${PWD}/wolumes/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
environment:
- VIRTUAL_HOST= *******
- LETSENCRYPT_HOST= *******
- VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
ports:
- "8080:8080"
- "50000:50000"
restart: unless-stopped

Jenkins запускается внутри контейнера со следующими параметрами(выше код).Мне нужно jenkins дать доступ к docker на хосте.

Comment: Раз 5 перепрочёл вопрос и ничего не понял. Можно подробнее? Кого куда прописать, чтобы работало что? Вернее "кого", я понял и "куда" - тоже. Не понял "зачем".

Comment: Я запускаю контейнер с сервером jenkins.Для того чтобы в этом контейнере jenkins мог собирать имейджи для докера к примеру,мне необходимо контейнеру дать доступ к докеру на хостовой машине.Так называемый docker-in-docker.Для этого прописывается /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock и нужно контейнеру дать права на использование докера.Как это сделать я понять и пытаюсь.По идее нужно пользователя контейнера добавить в группу пользователей Docker  на хостовой машине.

Comment: Ээээ, а кто мешает контейнер дженкинса и докер-ин-докер объединить через докер композ и собирать внутри всё чё тебе надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откопал решение в недрах интернета

Большое значение, которое приносит контейнеризация, состоит в том, что все эти независимые контейнеры (фактически процессы) могут совместно использовать ядро. Это означает, что даже если на хосте докера запущены сотни или тысячи контейнеров, ноКонтролируемые ядром uid и gid по-прежнему только один набор, Таким образом, один и тот же uid представляет одного и того же пользователя в хосте и контейнере (даже если разные имена пользователей отображаются в разных местах).

Фактически ядром системы управляет только один uid 1000. На хост-машине он рассматривается как ник пользователя, а в контейнере - как пользователь-пользователь.

Таким образом, есть одна вещь, которую мы должны прояснить: внутри контейнера пользователь appuser может получить права и привилегии ника пользователя вне контейнера. Привилегия, предоставленная пользователю nick или uid 1000 на хост-машине, также будет предоставлена   appuser в контейнере.

Тоесть проще говоря,смотрем uid в контейнре(допустим 1000),создаем в системе пользователя с uid 1000 и этому пользователю даем права доступа к docker.sock
При прописанном -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock это дает нам доступ контейнера к docker на хостовой системе.